How can I enable numlock on login? [Ubuntu 24.10]
I recently installed ubuntu 24.10 but im unable to auto enable numlock when I login.
I tried by installing numlockx but I think its applicable only for x11 and ubuntu 24 runs on wayland. Can someone tell me how to enable here?
OS Details:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.10
Release:    24.10
Codename:   oracular

this is usually set in BIOS

I got answer:
switch to super user context
run below command to show current status:

gsettings list-recursively | grep -e numlock

run below command to set numlock on

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard remember-numlock-state true


gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state on

